# Unable to run - shows console error "This version of popup-menu requires RN 0.55+. Check our compatibility table."

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I'm using the library "react-native-popup-menu".
But now I'm completely stuck in the above error. Nothing found helpful from my research.

Thank you in advance for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native Popup Menu has a [compatibility table](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu). Version 0.13 requires React Native 0.55 (16.3.1); 0.9–0.12.6 require 0.40 or later.

You either need to upgrade your React Native project to 0.55, or downgrade React Native Popup Menu to 0.12.6.